# Sample Application Using Drools5

Tags: drools

I am working on the Drools5.I am new to this Drools.I need a sample working example for this Drools.For this i have googled it alot but i did not find the correct one.If anyone has an idea can give me the reply.

Comment: What's wrong with the samples available here: http://legacy.drools.codehaus.org/Tutorials+and+Examples

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm on the same boat as you are, I've searched for learning material quite a bit. Here are my resources:

http://www.jboss.org/drools For the general portal for the project.

Since this project has nicely modularized submodules, here they are:

1. [Drools Guvnor](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-guvnor.html) for the Management Module that is used to manage packages of rules and POJOs with versions and also for deployment of snapshots for external usage.
2. [Drools Expert](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-expert.html) for the expert systems core of the project. Here you can get a first look at how rule processing works under drools.
3. [Drools jBPM5](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm) for business workflow process modeling and integration.
4. [Drools Fusion](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-fusion.html) for Complex Event Processing (CEP) with which you can do all timeconstraint sorts of pattern matching you could think of (my favorite by the way ;).
5. [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner.html) for planning and business resource optimization.

For each of them, there is a complete and in my opinion high quality [documentation](http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads) out. In there you can really get a hands on an start digging in. You could also start working through one or the other of my personal list:

- [Getting started with drools fusion](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/getting-started-with-drools-fusion/#comments), by TheJavaDude
- [Creating Category, Package, Declarative Model, Rules And Snapshot In Drools Guvnor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=585tmSp5HXU&feature=BFa&list=PL106C6B66AC0A8CD4)[Video]
- [Mark Proctors introduction to drools at FOSDEM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nqOyuvGBHs)[Video]

I hope this helps.

Greetings,
Kjellski